# TypeError: unbound method move_to_element() must be called with ActionChains ins tance as first argument (got list instance instead)

Tags: jquery, python, selenium

I'm using selenium (most current version) and python 2.7.8. I'm receiving the following error message when attempting to drag and drop to a `<div id="droppable">` using jquery ui. `TypeError: unbound method move_to_element() must be called with ActionChains ins
tance as first argument (got list instance instead)`

In fact, my code here is testing this out on the jQuery UI website's droppable page. The code I'm using looks like this:

```
   def testStep4(self):
    # Dragging and dropping a page element
    self.driver.switch_to_frame(self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)
    element = self.driver.find_elements_by_id("droppable")
    action_chains.ActionChains.move_to_element(element)
```

The jQuery UI code I'm attempting to manipulate is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
  #droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
  </style>
  <script>
   $(function() {
   $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
   $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
     drop: function( event, ui ) {
       $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
          .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be most appreciated. I'm just confused. I was using the `drag_and_drop` selenium object, but it was returning the same exact error message. I feel like I'm getting closer to having this figured out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use the singular form `find_element_by_id` so that you get only one element, and not a list. I see no reason in your situation to use `find_elements_by_id`. Then you need to instantiate an `ActionChains` object and call `move_to_element` on it and then `perform` to have it perform the actions. So something like this:

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_id("droppable")
action_chains.ActionChains(driver) \
    .move_to_element(element) \
    .perform()
```

If what you want to do a complete drag and drop in one go you should do:

```
target = self.driver.find_element_by_id("droppable")
source = self.driver.find_element_by_id("draggable")
action_chains.ActionChains(driver) \
    .drag_and_drop(source, target) \
    .perform()
```

Comment: Thank you, Louis. This modification did run with a pass; however, the visible output did not move the draggable to the droppable. Is there a way to identify the what you are moving? I changed it to `action_chains.ActionChains(self.driver).drag_and_drop(element, target).perform()` with using my current element as the target and the draggable as my element.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I had incorrectly figured you wanted to move to the element first to do whatever it is you wanted to do. I guess what you want to do is the drag and drop in one go. The edit addresses this.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I originally wanted to do, but was receiving error messages. So I tried the other with error. I just wasn't adding `.perform()` at the end of the statement.